# Address of a hardware register from acces macro

Tags: c

I have a list of registers defined using the usual format

```
#define REG_NAME (*(volatile unsigned int *) 0x1000)
```

Somewhere in my code I want to get `0x1000` in a `switch case` using `REG_NAME`.
How do i go about it ?

I tried using `switch(&REG_NAME)` and `switch(*REG_NAME)` without success, it throws a compiler error:

> expression must have integral type

Comment: I edited post to make REG_NAME value at the address 0x1000, the usual way to access register.

Answer (score 2):

Your macro must be defined like this:

```
#define REG_NAME (*(volatile unsigned int *) 0x1000)
```

Then you can use `REG_NAME` to get the value stored in the register. If you want to get the register address (your `0x1000` value here) as an integer (e.g., an `int`), you have to use `(int) &REG_NAME`. The cast is needed here as `&REG_NAME` is of a pointer type.

How you defined your macro was incorrect as the cast operator requires parentheses around the type name.

Comment: I think you mean `#define REG_NAME ((volatile unsigned int *) 0x1000)` so that the address is no longer dereferenced

Comment: @BrianSidebotham no, I meant with the dereference, but my `*REG_NAME` was actually a `REG_NAME`; fixed.

Comment: Ah yes, looks better!

Answer (score 1):

Here, REG_NAME is a dereferenced pointer - i.e. it's a value contained in a register and should be treated as such throughout the code. Trying to use the same define for multiple purposes (both value and address) is confusing at best!

You're better off having something along the lines of:

```
#define REG_TYPE(x)      (*(volatile unsigned int*)x)
#define REG_NAME_ADDR    (0x1000)
#define REG_NAME         REG_TYPE(REG_NAME_ADDR)
```

If the registers are already defined in a header file provided by the processor manufacturer you'll have to create your own defines to solve the problem.

Comment: I cannot define my own as above cause there are multiple instances of an I2C device with identical Register structure which them selves are captured as struct.  #define I2C0   (*(volatile I2C_tag *) 0xFFD80000UL) #define I2C1   (*(volatile I2C_tag *) 0xFFD90000UL) where I2C_tag is a struct of I2C registers. Some where in my code I   should be able to differentiate b/w them using the instance passed . For ex : void reset(volatile I2C_tag *instance) { switch (int)&instance.... }